# Pivot Table Formatting returns error

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, vba

I am working on a macro in which I am putting together PivotTables.

My Problem:
I can not get the calculation part to work. I get an error everytime I run the code at the stage where PivotField(18) is supposed to calculate the .Function=xlCount. The error I get is "1004 select method of range class failed".

All the examples I've found online and in the MS Help section are structured the way I have set up my code. What am I missing???

Any help is highly appreciated...

I've been working on this the better part of the day. The following page ([Link](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/)) has been super helpful, but hasn't helped me in cracking this particular problem.

```
' Start of PivotSpecific Formatting
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT" & wsNewWorksheetName)
With pt
    ' Prevent AutoFormatting of Columns
    .HasAutoFormat = False
    ' Hide Field Headers
    .DisplayFieldCaptions = False
    .TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium2"
    ' Apply calculation to numbers and change Caption
    With .PivotFields(18)
        .Caption = "Demand"
        .Function = xlCount
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    End With
    With .PivotFields(15)
        .Caption = "Lowest OP"
        .Function = xlMin
        .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End With
End With
```

Update 1: Screenshot of Pivot Table
[image: Pivot Table Screenshot]

Update 2: Tested Code from bonCodigo
Here is the code adjusted to my workbook. With this I get a run time error 91 on the line:
Set pvField = pvTable.PivotFields(18)

```
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
Dim pvTable As PivotTable
Dim pvField As PivotField

Set wkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNewWorksheetName)
Set pvTble = wkSheet.PivotTables("PT" & wsNewWorksheetName)
Set pvField = pvTable.PivotFields(18)

With pvField
     .Caption = "Demand"
     .Function = xlCount
     .orientation = xlDataField
     .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With

Set pvField = Nothing
Set pvTable = Nothing
Set wkSheet = Nothing
```

Comment: Can you show us how your pivot table looks like? And what results you are expecting by this code? Are you only getting error in `.Function = xlCount`? how about `.function = xlMin`? What's the name of your `.PivotFields(18)` ? Are you sure it's `count`? or is it something else like `sum`?

Comment: @bonCodigo I'm getting it on both the .Function= that are in the code. I'll upload a screenshot of the table.

Comment: @bonCodigo The names of the PivotFields(18) is "Nachfrage"... however, I would like to not use the name because the application will be used on various computers, not all of which will have the same language settings... this means that the "Anzahl von " (in english "Count of") could cause problems when running the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this please and comment with your results. So we can see from there.

```
Option Explicit

'-- whatever other code you may have... 

Dim wkSheet as Worksheet
Dim pvTable as PivotTable
Dim pvField as PivotField

Set wkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '-- user proper sheet name explicitly
Set pvTble = wkSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1") 
   ' or wkSheet.PivotTables(1) '-- use pivot table name or index
Set pvField = pvTable.PivotFields("SomeField") '-- use pivot field name or index

' -- do whatever you want to do with the pivot table

' -- do what you need to do with the pivot field
With pvField
     .Caption = "Demand"
     .Orientation = xlDataField '--<< THIS could well be the culprit
     .Function = xlCount
     .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With

Set pvField = Nothing
Set PvTable = Nothing
Set wkSheet = Nothing
```

---

Since you have more than one field to format, I recommend you to use a loop if they are consecutive using `DataFields Index`

e.g. `pvTable.DataFields(1).Function = xlCount`

Otherwise you will have to define them separately. It is always best to assign an variable as a reference to the object that you intend to interact. :)

Comment: Updated with `orientation`, please test it out.

Comment: I inserted the `.orientation`, but it actually stops before it even gets there... i get the runtime error on `Set pvField = pvTable.PivotFields(18)`

Comment: Can you use the Explicit sheet, pivot name and FieldName then test out? Try to narrow down the line where you are getting the error.

Comment: Did what you recommended: The error apperantly occures on the PivotTable Selection. `Set wkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNewWorksheetName)
wkSheet.Select
Set pvTble = wkSheet.PivotTables("PT" & wsNewWorksheetName)
pvTable.TableRange1.Select
Set pvField = pvTable.PivotFields("ANZAHL NACHFRAGE")
pvField.DataRange.Select`

Comment: Oddly it lets me continue without raising an error on the `Set` statement, but if I try to use the object afterwards, then I get the error.

Comment: Why do you want to `SELECT`? Just remove those performance cracking selections :( When you are setting you are already tracking those objects... Just please use the code as I have given to you without anything else. As recommended do not even use any variable names for names. Just use pure system names, like Sheet1 blah blah... something wrong with one of your name variables I reckon.

Comment: I don't want to use Select... i added it simply to see how far the code goes before it produces an error. In fact, I did at first use just the code you gave me. That produced the error on the line specified above `Set pvField = pvTable.PivotFields(18)` That is what you meant, right?

Comment: I changed `Set pvTble = wkSheet.PivotTables("PT" & wsNewWorksheetName)` to `Set pvTable = wkSheet.PivotTables(1)` and now it suddenly works! :) Thank you so much for your help!!! I spent the entire morning on this. Happy to have a solution!

Comment: I am relieved and glad you worked it out. As for the best guess, setting objects with a wrong name has caused the disaster. :-)  so when you want to access that object, there's is nothing like that exists. So bomb. +1 for your perseverance.

Comment: Thanks. I'd say +1 for yours!